# Does an Operating System check every Instruction?

Tags: memory, operating-system, cpu

Not sure if anyone here can answer this.

I've learned that an Operating System checks if an instruction of a program changes something outside of its allocated memory, and if it does then the OS won't allow the program to do this.

But, if the OS has to check this for every instruction, won't this take up at least 5/6 of the CPU?  I tried to replicate this, and this is how many clock cycles I've come up with to check this for every instruction.

If I've understood something wrong, please correct me, because I can't imagine that an OS takes up that much of the CPU.

Comment: There is hardware assist.   The simplest ones have two modes, privileged and user.  User isn't allowed to touch privileged registers or memory addresses (typically enforced by page tables, which can only be created by the privileged bit).   More complex ones have finer grained capabilities, so that some system registers are available, or present preset values to pretend they are available.

Answer (score 0):

There are several safe-guards in place to ensure a non-privileged process behaves. I will discuss two of them in the context of the x86_64 architecture, but these concepts (mostly) extend to other major platforms.

### Privilege Levels

There is a bit in a particular CPU register that indicates the current *privilege level*. These privileges are often called *rings*, where ring 0 corresponds to the kernel (ie. highest privilege), and ring 3 corresponds to a userspace process (ie. lowest privilege). There are other rings, but they're not relevant to this introduction.

Certain instructions in x86_64 may only be executed by privileged processes. The current ring must be 0 to execute a privileged instruction. If you try to execute this instruction without the correct privileges, the processor raises a [general protection fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_protection_fault). The kernel synchronously processes this interrupt, and will almost certainly kill the userspace process.

The ring level can only be changed while in ring 0, so the userspace process can't simply change from ring 3 to ring 0 by itself.

### Execute Permission in Page Tables

All instructions to be executed are stored in memory. Many architectures (including x86_64) use [page tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) to store mappings from virtual addresses to physical addresses. These page tables have several bookkeeping entries as well, one of which is an *execute permission bit*. If this bit is not set for a page that corresponds to the instruction trying to be executed, then the processor will produce a general protection fault. As before, the kernel will synchronously process this interrupt, and likely kill the offending process.

When are these execute bits set? They can be dynamically set via `mmap(2)`, but in most cases the compiler emits special CODE sections in the binaries it generates, and when the OS loads the binary into memory it sets the execute bit in the page table entries for the pages that correspond to the CODE sections.

### Who's checking these bits?

You're right to ask about the performance penalty of an OS checking these bits for every single instruction. If the OS were doing this, it would be prohibitively expensive. Instead, the processor supports privilege levels and page tables (with the execute bit). The OS can set these bits, and rely on the processor to generate interrupts when a process acts outside its privileges.

These hardware checks are *very* fast.